# CardLayout Manager Questions/Confusion

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I'm currently working on a program which I've asked [questions involving previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401284/compiler-issues).

I've made a good amount of progress since then, and now I'm ready to begin on the infoPanel portion of the client program. I've read through the documentation and other questions, but I'm a still a bit confused. How do I setup the panel to, y'know, work? How do I link it with the JList(If that's even possible to use a JList instead of a combo box), and then how do I establish which selection references which card?

Thank you so much for any assistance!

Source:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ClientApp extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientApp();
    }


    public ClientApp()
    {
        this.setSize(320,380);
        this.setTitle("Honeydukes Candy Order");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        JPanel invntryPanel = new JPanel();


        String[] candy = {"Acid Pops", "Bat's Blood Soup",
                          "Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans",
                          "Blood-flavoured Lollipops",
                          "Cauldron Cakes", "Charm Choc",
                          "Chocoballs", "Chocolate Cauldrons",
                          "Chocolate Frogs", "Chocolate Skeletons",
                          "Chocolate Wands", "Choco-Loco", "Cockroach Clusters",
                          "Nougat", "Crystallised Pineapple",
                          "Drooble's Best Blowing Gum", "Exploding Bonbons",
                          "Toffees", "Fizzing Whizzbees",
                          "Fudge Flies", "Ice Mice",
                          "Jelly Slugs", "Liquourice Wands",
                          "Pepper Imps", "Peppermint Toads",
                          "Pink Coconut Ice", "Pixie Puffs",
                          "Pumpkin Fizz", "Salt Water Taffy",
                          "Shock-o-Choc", "Skeletal Sweets",
                          "Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders",
                          "Sugar Quills", "Sugared Butterfly Wings",
                          "Toothflossing Stringmints", "Tooth-Splintering Strongmints",
                          "Treacle Fudge", "Chocolates", "Wizochoc"};
        JList candyList = new JList(candy);
        candyList.setVisibleRowCount(18);
        candyList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(candyList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                             JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        invntryPanel.add(scroll);

        JPanel startCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel acidPopsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel batsBloodSoupCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel bertieBottsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel bloodPopsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel cauldronCakesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel charmChocCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocoballsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocCauldronsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocFrogsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocSkeleCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocWands = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocolocoCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel roachClustersCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel nougatCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel crystalPineappleCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel droobleGumCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel explodeBonbonsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel toffeesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel fizzWhizCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel fudgeFliesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel iceMiceCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel jellySlugsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel liquorWandsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pepImpsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pinkCocoIceCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pixiePuffsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pumpkFizzCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel saltTaffeyCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel shockChocCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel skeleSweetsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel spindleSpidersCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel sugarQuillsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel sugarWingsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel flossMintsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel splintMintsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel treacleFudgeCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocolatesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel wizochocCard = new JPanel();

        infoPanel.add(startCard);
        infoPanel.add(acidPopsCard);
        infoPanel.add(batsBloodSoupCard);
        infoPanel.add(bertieBottsCard);
        infoPanel.add(bloodPopsCard);
        infoPanel.add(cauldronCakesCard);
        infoPanel.add(charmChocCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocoballsCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocCauldronsCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocFrogsCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocSkeleCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocWands);
        infoPanel.add(chocolocoCard);
        infoPanel.add(roachClustersCard);
        infoPanel.add(nougatCard);
        infoPanel.add(crystalPineappleCard);
        infoPanel.add(droobleGumCard);
        infoPanel.add(explodeBonbonsCard);
        infoPanel.add(toffeesCard);
        infoPanel.add(fizzWhizCard);
        infoPanel.add(fudgeFliesCard);
        infoPanel.add(iceMiceCard);
        infoPanel.add(jellySlugsCard);
        infoPanel.add(liquorWandsCard);
        infoPanel.add(pepImpsCard);
        infoPanel.add(pinkCocoIceCard);
        infoPanel.add(pixiePuffsCard);
        infoPanel.add(pumpkFizzCard);
        infoPanel.add(saltTaffeyCard);
        infoPanel.add(shockChocCard);
        infoPanel.add(skeleSweetsCard);
        infoPanel.add(spindleSpidersCard);
        infoPanel.add(sugarQuillsCard);
        infoPanel.add(sugarWingsCard);
        infoPanel.add(flossMintsCard);
        infoPanel.add(splintMintsCard);
        infoPanel.add(treacleFudgeCard);
        infoPanel.add(chocolatesCard);
        infoPanel.add(wizochocCard);

        this.add(invntryPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a ListSelectionListener to the JList, and inside of that listener change the card displayed by the CardLayout.

You really need to read the [tutorial on how to use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) first though as there you'd see that your add method is wrong. Consider using the Strings held by the JList as the constant that you'd use when adding components to the CardLayout-using panel.